# Why does my python program always show the opposite reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Ok, so I am making a file keeping software in python which will let users make, delete and upload files to a secret folder in the program.

Here is the part i am having trouble with:

```
user = input("User :")

if user is "Aymen":
     print("Welcome")

else:
     print("Access denied")
```

Why does my program regardless of the right input always show "Access denied"?

Comment: `is` is used to compare data structure types, `==` is to compare values.

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg, `is` is used to check the identity  of an object not to compare types

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg I think you're thinking of `isinstance`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `is` to test for equivalence, use `==`

`is` is a keyword to test if two values are the same exact instance in memory. But just because two things are equal does not mean that Python actually thinks they're the same object stored in one location. It's most commonly used with `None` but never in the way you're using it.

You should use

```
if user == "Aymen":
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` instead of `is` for comparing strings. `is` ***tests for identity , not equality***. That means Python simply compares the memory address a object resides in.

Example -

```
>>> s = input("Enter : ")
Enter : Aymen
>>> s is "Aymen"
False
>>> s == "Aymen"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare to strings or variables, use "==", not "is". "is" is for testing, not comparing two variables or strings.

```
if user == "Aymen":
     print("Welcome")
```